# Using TLE2426 as opamp rails supplies

Tags: operational-amplifier

I want to power two opamp rails with +-12V.
For that I want to use [this](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/voltage-references/0284220/) component to obtain +/-12V split supply from a 24V single supply.

But I came across the following statement:

> TLE2426 splits the opamp rails and references signal ground but not
>   output ground.

What does that mean? Can I use use TLE2426 to power rail-to-rail opamp rails?

Comment: USe the proper data sheet http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/tle2426.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That device is a virtual ground maker. That is, it creates a reference point half way between the rails. You would supply your op-amps with 24V and Ground and use the output of this device as your signal/analog ground.

Something like this.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqyRjI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note internals of the rail-splitter is simply a voltage divider and a unity gain op-amp buffer.

[image]

As such it can't source or sink more than 20mA so do not use it for higher currents.

**Addition:** Note the circuit can be equally labelled as follows.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhCmKS.png)</sup>

Comment: Is there any benefit over using this rather than an op amp (other than, maybe, fewer components) for the virtual ground? I've often used two equal resistors creating half +V into the positive of the op amp and just set it up as a voltage follower.

Comment: @DiBosco Looking at the spec sheet that's basically all it is anyway, a divider and an op-amp. Benefit is the simple 3 pin package I guess.

Comment: @Trevor It means this device is not what I need. Do you know a single IC which can supply +/-12V from 24V? A single IC which wouldn't need many many extra components.

Comment: I foud this: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1044afa.pdf

Comment: Can this be used to create -12V from 12V supply. So I can use -+12V for rails. My concern is max rating is 13V very close to 12V.

Comment: @doncarlos yes something like that might work if the current is sufficient. Though you have not intimated WHY you need the negative rail yet.

Comment: because input will swing from -10V to +10V.

Comment: @doncarlos see my addition to the answer.

Comment: @Trevor I need something more versatile. I might use the split rails for more than one opamp. TLE2426  seems needed for each opamp. Is that correct?

Comment: @doncarlos depends how much current the op-amp circuits take.

Comment: @doncarlos If you need a lot more current then you are better off creating proper +-12V rails in the first place.

Comment: @Trevor See this: http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/adcin_se_diff/image002.gif Its a single to diff-ended converter. Can I use a single TLE2426's output as common for all opmaps here? if the currents are low

Comment: Or better stick with something like LTC1044? Price doesn't matter

Comment: @doncarlos you need to stop confusing signals with power. The ecircuit you show produces two reference signals, and is not a power supply. You also have to power those op-amps with some rail beyond those voltages. I can't tell you what to stick with since it depends on the whole circuit, not just this part. But usually the LTC device is meant for a quick circuit. It's not intended to be the reference for say a whole stereo system.

Comment: But I meant powering the rails of the opamps, they are not shown in that image

Comment: @doncarlos yes I know they are not shown, but they are still there... and need to be higher / lower than the outputs.

Comment: @doncarlos sigh I am confused... is that ecircuit what you are trying to power?

Comment: yes thats why I might need something like this. ?
 https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/ICL7662-Si7661.pdf

Comment: Where does the 24V come from and where does the output connect to...

Comment: @Trevor I will draw  whole circuit with a buf634 http://tangentsoft.net/elec/bitmaps/vgrounds/buffer.png might take a while i will link it here

Comment: @Trevor I opened a new question regarding this: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/331371/problem-in-using-a-buffered-virtual-ground-as-opamp-split-supply

Answer (score 3):

> TLE2426 splits the opamp rails and references signal ground but not output ground.

The source/sink capability of the TLE2426 is only \$ \pm 20 \$ mA. So, you would not reference any sizable output load to this virtual ground.

For example, if you were driving a speaker, you would tie one terminal of the speaker to your negative supply and AC couple from the output of your opamp to the other terminal of the speaker.