# Problem in using a buffered virtual ground as opamp split supply

Tags: operational-amplifier, virtual-ground, split

The single-ended to differential converter on the right side works fine in sim only if I set opamp rails Vcc=12V and Vee=-12V as split supply. But if I supply the circuit by using 24V supply and a buffered virtual ground circuit as below it doesn't work:

[image]

I found the example usage of the [BUF634](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/buf634.pdf) here:
[image]

What can be the problem?

Comment: Define "doesn't works" with results on all pertinent nodes. You ought to know better by now.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 I get nonsense output from the converter if I use that virtual gnd circuit. Am I wiring it wrong?

Comment: "nonsense output" is not much of an engineering term. Try again. Describe what you actually see using actual engineering terminology.

Comment: simulate and see, otherwise i have to upload plots and have to leave home now. I use LTspice

Comment: The BUF634 is a high-current, high-frequency device. I somehow doubt that you are using good ground (preferably ground plane) construction, and your schematic shows no decoupling - that 220 uF doesn't count.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast do you mean i need to add decoupling caps between Vcc and VGnd and Vee and VGnd? i gotta leave now i will answer later thanks

Comment: @doncarlos - I mean a decoupling cap, say 1 uF ceramic, between Vcc and Vee as close to the BUF pins as possible. Same with U1 and U2. And you need to learn about ground layout, too. Thick, short grounds.

Comment: the issue is in simulation not implemented on any board.

Comment: 220k is a pretty large divider value for an IC with uA's of input bias current. Also work much better with opamp and run in closed loop.

Comment: replace gnd symbol with a wire ... is this earth gnd in your sim? or does Vcc,Vee give +/- 12V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NO idea what you mean by doesn't work.. Works fine here..

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0vpO9.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks adding those 100nF C2 and C3 solved the problem. Do I need C4 in my case where I use a BUF634?

Comment: my circuit works fine. just having 200mV ripples at Vcc rails. If I use 100 Ohm and 100u as LP filter on rails it mitigates, but 100u is a bit too much,

Comment: @doncarlos where is the ripple coming from... the supply itself? ANyways, more caps...

Comment: Ripples are originating from BUF634, and appearing at Vcc and Vee